# Prove that $Df(x) = f'(x)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C^1[0, 1]$ be the set of all continuously differentiable functions on $[0, 1]$, and let D be the differentiation operator, defined by $Df(x) = f'(x)$ for all $f ∈ C
^1[0, 1]$.
Prove that D is a linear operator mapping $C^1[0, 1]$ onto $C[0, 1]$. Prove that D is continuous with respect to the norm $||f||_{C^1[0,1]} = max_{0≤x≤1}|f(x)| + max_{0≤x≤1}|f'(x)|$.

Proof idea:

Linearity $D(\alpha f+\beta g)(x)=(\alpha f+\beta g)'(x)=\alpha f'(x)+\beta g'(x)=\alpha Df+\beta Dg$. And since $f\in C^1[0,1]$ continuously differentiable, then $f'\in C[0,1]$ and thus $D:C^1[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ is well defined.

Secondly $D$ is bounded and thus continuous. $||Df||_{C^1[0,1]}=||f'(x)||_{C[0,1]}=max_{0≤x≤1}|f'(x)|=||f||_{C^1[0,1]} - max_{0≤x≤1}|f(x)|\leq ||f||_{C^1[0,1]}$ bounded being continuous on closed interval. So $||Df||$ is bounded and thus continuous. Do I need to find an exact $||D||$ value here?

I am uncertain whether the proof is correct or complete.
Thanks,

Comment: No, there is no need to find $\|D\|$. Your proof is complete.